# Is there a way for format the Solspace Calendar dates in UnixTimestamp?

Tags: solspace, calendar

I'm currently developing a multilingual site that uses Solspace Calendar as a calendering tool. Since it is multilingual, I will need to 'translate' the outputted days to either dutch, french or english.

Since the locale is english, it outputs this by default.

I tried using Hippo's Time/Date converter - and it's correctly called within the {occurrences} tags but the output within those tags are formatted in a way that the Hippo plugin doesn't understand them.

Is anyone aware of way to format the output of Caledar to a unixtimestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not to use `format="%U"`?

From the documentation of Solspace Calendar:

> In addition to standard EE date formatting, Calendar supports[...]

From the [documentation of EECMS](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html):

> %U: seconds since the epoch

Comment: I wasn't able to close the topic. Found the answer right after posting it - but my stack exchange rep isn't high enough :/

Comment: If the question is duplicated, I can close it for you. If it isn't, just mark the answer as right and help other people looking for the same answer.